# Clojure unable to read input csv file

Tags: clojure, anglican

I am trying to read [this csv file](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/tree/master/Chapter1_Introduction/data) as a list. I downloaded the csv file and ran the following code in a gorilla REPL notebook, which is also located in the same directory as the csv file.

```
(use 'nstools.ns)
(ns+ message-example
     (:like anglican-user.worksheet)
     (:require [clojure-csv.core :as csv]
               [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn take-csv
  [fname]
  (with-open [file (io/reader fname)]
    (csv/parse-csv (slurp file))))

(def data
  (map (comp read-string first) (take-csv "txtdata.csv")))
```

The gorilla REPL throws the following error.

```
An exception was caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException (Attempting to call unbound fn: #'message-example/take-csv)
throwArity - (Var.java:43)
invoke - (AFn.java:32)
applyToHelper - (AFn.java:154)
applyTo - (AFn.java:144)
```

I am unable to understand what am I doing wrong. Can you please help?

Comment: Sounds like you need to reload/reinitialize your repl?  It seems to be not finding/recognizing the definition of the `take-csv` function.

Comment: @AlanThompson Still doesn't work..

Comment: You should have `(csv/take-csv "...")`.

Comment: To clarify what @akond said, you haven't namespace-qualified your reference to that function, so the compiler is trying to resolve it in your current namespace, which it can't. Use the namespace-qualified name or `:refer` the functions you want in your `require`.

Comment: @akond: I tried following your suggestion. Still does not work.. The error says `java.lang.RuntimeException (No such namespace: csv)`

Comment: I find it difficult to beleive, because you are using the namespace already: `(csv/parse-csv (slurp file))`

Comment: I just checked.. the error actually comes from this `(csv/parse-csv `